# ¿Debo colocar el atributo lang en la etiqueta button?

Tags: html, atributos

Me surgió la duda de si la etiqueta button necesita el atributo **lang** o basta con que esté solo en la etiqueta **HTML**.

Mí duda viene porque estaba leyendo sobre **button** en *mdm web docs* y en la página tienen una tabla con los atributos y aparece este que menciono con la indicación de que lo fija el navegador por defecto, pero justo abajo pone entre comillas "desconocido" y eso me generó la confusión.

Comment: sólo si el button/elemento está en un lenguage diferente al especificado en el html, por lo general los lectores de texto a voz usan ese attr para cambiar la pronunciación

Comment: @aloMalbarez Muchas gracias por la respuesta.